# Powershell azure get oauth token for application authentication

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication, azure-active-directory

I'm using powershell and have connected to Azure using `Connect-AzAccount`. I've got some function apps running in with Azure authentication in-front of them. I can't figure out how to generate tokens from the powershell session using the connected/authenticated account.

I am able to do this in powershell using a clientID & Secret and calling the token endpoint. But I want to use my own credentials so we don't need secrets, I'd expect this to work in a similar way that we do with `az cli`

For example, I've authenticated with `az cli` and can generate valid tokens like below using `az account get-access-token --resource "api://83.....`

[image: az cli account get-access-token]

I've tired using `Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "api://83.....` and errors like below.

*Get-AzAccessToken: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. Token acquisition failed for user {}.onmicrosoft.com. Ensure that you have authenticated with a developer tool that supports Azure single sign on.*

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-noninteractive?view=azps-11.0.0#login-with-a-managed-identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, I got the **same error** as below:

```
Connect-AzAccount
Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "api://cbae8e36-72b8-425b-a9f7XXXX"
```

[image]

Make use of **`$DebugPreference = "Continue"`** before executing the command to understand what is causing the error.

```
$DebugPreference = "Continue"
```

[image]

***I found the detailed error after the debugging:***

> AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2' named 'Microsoft Azure PowerShell'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

[image]

The error ***"Get-AzAccessToken : SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. Token acquisition failed for user user@XXX.onmicrosoft.com. Ensure that you have authenticated with a developer tool that supports Azure single sign on".*** usually occurs if the Microsoft Azure PowerShell (1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2) is not consented to use the application.

**To resolve the error**, *Go to your Azure AD Application -> Expose an API -> Add a client application -> And add 1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2 as Authorized client applications*

[image]

After the above setting, **I am able to fetch the access token successfully like below**:

```
Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "api://cbae8e36-72b8-425b-a9f7XXXX"
```

[image]

***Output:***

```
Token     : Token
ExpiresOn : 11/27/2023 1:51:16 PM +00:00
Type      : Bearer
TenantId  : TenantID
UserId    : User@XXX.onmicrosoft.com
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I had already updated this so that az cli was exposed, it never crossed my mind to do this for powershell.